# Find all ranges of consecutive numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, ecmascript-6

Given a sorted array of numbers, how do you get ranges of consecutive numbers? The function should return ranges and single numbers as a string. Example:

```
function findRanges(arrayOfSortedNumbers) {
  // logic here
}

findRanges([1, 3, 4, 5, 7]) => (expected output: "1, 3-5, 7")

findRanges([1, 2, 3, 5]) => (expected output: "1-3, 5")

findRanges([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) => (expected output: "2-6")
```

Sorry for not being able to explain the problem better.

Comment: `(expected output:` **REAL CODE** `)` [mcve]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide what have you tried so far?

Comment: How about a hint instead.
1 - sort your array
2 - starting with the first element walk forward in the array
3 - if the next item is previous item + 1 then keep walking
4 - otherwise, add the range you just discovered into a result array
5 - continue on with  your current item as the new first item.
6 - the rest you should be able to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do it:

1. Sort the array (safety)
2. Iterate over the array with `reduce` to create an object containing the `ranges` and the start of the active range (`rangeStart`).
3. On the first iteration, push the first element in the ranges and save this element as the `rangeStart`
4. On the successive iterations, if the value equals the last value + 1, we are in the same range, so we update it by changing the last value in the `ranges` array. Otherwise, we push the element in the `ranges` array and update `rangeStart` to be this element.
5. Return the `ranges` property of the object output by `reduce` and join it using commas.

```js
function findRanges(numbers) {
  return [...numbers].sort((a, b) => a - b).reduce((acc, x, i) => {
    if (i === 0) {
      acc.ranges.push(x);
      acc.rangeStart = x;
    } else {
      if (x === acc.last + 1) {
        acc.ranges[acc.ranges.length-1] = acc.rangeStart + '-' + x;
      } else {
        acc.ranges.push(x);
        acc.rangeStart = x;
      }
    }
    acc.last = x;
    return acc;
  }, { ranges: [] }).ranges.join(', ');
}

console.log(findRanges([1, 3, 4, 5, 7]));
console.log(findRanges([1, 2, 3, 5]));
console.log(findRanges([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
```